# Apps Script Google Sheets Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates a new Google Sheet file and names it based on a variable in a different sheet. After the sheet is created I am trying to copy all data from a template sheet, including merged cells and formatting. The scrip currently works in all aspects except the formatting. I am having a very hard time to get it to work. I would even be fine with just duplicating the sheet and having it rename based on my previous criteria.

```
function createNewSheet(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var name = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
  var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Job Traveler-" + name);
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl()).getId();

  importRange("1X4iOzc_shcOR8UM7OEM4F1-eR62YZmwKWyyEuu59Pf4","Job!A1:D", ssNew,"Sheet1!A1");
  

}

 
function importRange(sourceId,sourceRange,destinationID,destinationRangeStart) {
    var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceId);
    var sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
    var sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

    var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
    var destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
    var destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());
    var row = destStartRange.getRow();
    var col = destStartRange.getColumn();
    var rows = sourceVals.length;
    var cols = sourceVals[0].length;
    destSheet.getRange(row,col,rows,cols).setValues(sourceVals);

    var merged = sourceRng.getMergedRanges();
    var rowOffset = destStartRange.getRow()-sourceRng.getRow();
    var columnOffset = destStartRange.getColumn()-sourceRng.getColumn();

    for( var i=0; i<merged.length; i++ ) {
      row = merged[i].getRow()+rowOffset;
      col = merged[i].getColumn()+columnOffset;
      rows = merged[i].getNumRows();
      cols = merged[i].getNumColumns();
      destSheet.getRange(row,col,rows,cols).merge();
    }
 

  }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. I am no expert so I do apologize.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from one of my projects where I set the border and fill color

```
  for (i = 0; i < numCount; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i + row2SetValues, col2SetValues).setValue(randNumbers[i]);
  }
    sheet.getRange(row2SetValues, col2SetValues, numCount, 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_LIGHT);
    sheet.getRange(row2SetValues, col2SetValues, numCount, 1).setBackground("#bdd4f9");
}
```

[image]